# PHP mail send multipart inconsistently working

Tags: php, email

I'm currently having issues with sending PHP multipart emails. I've been looking online to check my code is correct and it appears to be. I found some code on another Stack question and tweaked my code to ensure it was the same as the code that the developer said worked for them. The following code is part of a function:

```
$mime_boundary = 'Multipart_Boundary_x'.md5(time()).'x';

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$replyto .= "reply-to: $replyto";

$body = "This is a multi-part message in mime format.\r\n\r\n";

# Plain text
$body.= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
$body.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"charset=iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$body.= $text_content;
$body.= "\r\n";

# HTML
$body.= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
$body.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$body.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
$body.= $html_content;
$body.= "\r\n";

# End
$body.= "--$mime_boundary--\r\n";

$headers .= "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Sender-IP: $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']\r\n";
$headers .= 'Date: '.date('n/d/Y g:i A')."\r\n";
$replyto .= "reply-to: $replyto";

# Return
return mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

This works for most mail clients. It will appear in HTML in Mac Thunderbird and Gmail. However, there is someone on Windows 7 using Thunderbird and it is coming through as the HTML email with the html code showing rather than a HTML email.

Is there something I am doing wrong? And is there anything I need to configure on Apache to make this work? Help would be really appreciated as I'm just hitting brick walls with this at the moment.

Comment: I could spend a little while finding the issue with your code, or you could switch to PHPMailer and be done with the problem for good. Somethings aren't worth reinventing, and I really recommend using PHPMailer rather than building your own content

Comment: Hi @JamieBicknell, I understand what you're saying. I have been working with legacy code and server migration. I take what you're saying on board, I'll have a look at PHPMailer.

Comment: Definitely agreed with @JamieBicknell. PHP's built-in `mail()` function is a real pain to work with, it's flaky, and often insecure. You really should be switching to PHPMailer (or Swiftmailer) as soon as you can.

Comment: Thanks for the tips - I'm switching things now as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my comment above, I highly recommend you use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer), however, before I switched over the PHPMailer this was the format for sending multipart emails I used:

```
--52664dd6e3ea3
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hello

--52664dd6e3ea3
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/html"; boundary="html52664dd6e3ea3"

--html52664dd6e3ea3
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<strong>Hello</strong>

--html52664dd6e3ea3--
--52664dd6e3ea3--
```

And if you want attachments:

```
--52664e536e0b0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hello

--52664e536e0b0
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/html"; boundary="html52664e536e0b0"

--html52664e536e0b0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<strong>Hello</strong>

--html52664e536e0b0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=filename.ext
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

{BASE64CODEHERE}

--html52664e536e0b0--
--52664e536e0b0--
```

And multiple attachments here:

```
--52664e536e0b0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hello

--52664e536e0b0
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="text/html"; boundary="html52664e536e0b0"

--html52664e536e0b0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<strong>Hello</strong>

--html52664e536e0b0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=filename.ext
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

{BASE64CODEHERE}

--html52664e536e0b0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=filename.ext
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

{BASE64CODEHERE}

--html52664e536e0b0--
--52664e536e0b0--
```